# Symfony entity property not updating

Tags: php, many-to-many, symfony

I have a small questuion.

I have a article with repeatable property tags. When i editing exist article and add new tags all is ok. But if a remove tag from form in article this tag still exists.

As i understand post data binding to the form and to the entity. Thats way new tags appear in the material.

But why did they not disappear after binding new post data ?

```
   public function editAction(Article $article, Request $request)
    {
        // The second parameter is used to specify on what object the role is tested.
        if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('login');
        }

        // update Article modify date
        $article->setModifyDate(new \DateTime());

        // create form
        $form = $this->createForm(ArticleType::class, $article, [
            'manager' => $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
        ]);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        //print_r($article->getTags()); Deleted tag still here
```

**UPDATE**

Here is my **Article entity**

```
**
 * Class Article
 * @package BackendBundle\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="articles")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="BackendBundle\Entity\ArticleRepository")
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $alias;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $publishDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $modifyDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="articles", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *     name="articles_tags",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
     */
    private $tags;

    /**
     * Article constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set article name.
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Return article name.
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set articles alias.
     *
     * @param string $alias
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setAlias($alias)
    {
        $this->alias = $alias;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returns article alias.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAlias()
    {
        return $this->alias;
    }

    /**
     * Set article content.
     *
     * @param string $content
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Return article content
     * @return string
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * Set article author
     *
     * @param integer $author ID of author
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function setAuthor($author)
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Return author id.
     * @return int Id of the author.
     */
    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    /**
     * Set article publish date.
     *
     * @param string $date
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setPublishDate($date)
    {
        $this->publishDate = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Return article publish date.
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPublishDate()
    {
        return $this->publishDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set article modify date
     *
     * @param string $date
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setModifyDate($date)
    {
        $this->modifyDate = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Return article modify date
     * @return string
     */
    public function getModifyDate()
    {
        return $this->modifyDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set tags for article.
     *
     * @param  ArrayCollection|array $tags
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setTags($tags)
    {
        if (!empty($tags))
        {
            foreach ($tags as $tag)
            {
                $this->setTag($tag);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set article tag.
     *
     * @param Tag $tag
     *
     * @return $this
     *
     */
    public function setTag(Tag $tag)
    {
        if (!$this->tags->contains($tag))
        {
            $this->tags->set($tag->getName(), $tag);
            $tag->setArticle($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove all tags from article.
     */
    public function removeTags()
    {
        if(!empty($this->tags))
        {
            foreach($this->tags as $tag)
            {
                $this->removeTag($tag);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param \BackendBundle\Entity\Tag $tag
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function removeTag(Tag $tag)
    {
        if ($this->tags->contains($tag))
        {
            $this->tags->removeElement($tag);
            $tag->removeArticle($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returns all tags for article.
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->tags;
    }
}
```

And **ArticleType**

```
/**
 * Class ArticleType
 * @package AppBundle\Form
 */
class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $tagTransformer = new TagTransformer($options['manager']);
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, array(
                'label_attr' => array('class' => ''),
                'attr'       => array('class' => 'form-control'),
                'label'      => 'article.name'
            ))
            ->add('alias', TextType::class, array(
                'label_attr' => array('class' => ''),
                'attr'       => array('class' => 'form-control'),
                'label'      => 'article.alias'
            ))
            ->add('content', TextareaType::class, array(
                'label_attr' => array('class' => ''),
                'attr'       => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ),
                'label'      => 'article.content'
            ))
            ->add('publish_date', DateType::class, array(
                'label_attr' => array('class' => ''),
                'attr'       => array('class' => 'form-control'),
                'format'     => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
                'label'      => 'article.publish_date'
            ))
            ->add('modify_date', DateType::class, array(
                'label_attr' => array('class' => ''),
                'attr'       => array('class' => 'form-control'),
                'format'     => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
                'label'      => 'article.modify_date'
            ))
            ->add($builder->create('tags', CollectionType::class, array(
                'label'        => 'article.tags',
                'by_reference' => false,
                'allow_add'    => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
            ))->addViewTransformer($tagTransformer));
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'BackendBundle\Entity\Article',
        ));

        $resolver->setRequired(array(
            'manager',
        ));

        $resolver->setAllowedTypes('manager', 'Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify add tag and remove tag function in Article entity to something like this

```
public function addTag(Tag $tag)
{
    $this->tags[] = $tag;
    $tag->addArticle($this);

    return $this;
}

public function removeTag(Tag $tag)
{
    $this->tags->removeElement($tag);
    $tag->removeArticle($this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i have all this methods and more in my entity.

Comment: Can you update your question and show me your entity and form type ? So that i can help you to solve it.

Comment: Updated. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: did u forget to add form type of the collection ? Try to take a look at symfony documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: Very strange thing. I rename method setTag to AddTag and deleting start work. But saving new tags fails with HTTP ERROR 500 in dev mode

Comment: HTTP ERROR was problem in my code. I use old method with set* name.
So, i just rename set* method to add* and all is fine. Very thx for help.